# The View has Disappear when press home button

Tags: ios, iphone

I am develop IOS App ,and run the App on my iPhone.

I press the Home Button on iPhone , but when I click twice for Home button and turn to my App , it show the View like the following picture. The View is Disappear when I went back.

[image]

But I don't close the view at the `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear`.
And then when I click the App , it show the `blank View` like the following picture.

[image]

I have no idea about this...Can someone help me ?

Comment: What happens when you launch the app from here did you see the view?

Comment: @Rushi it show the blank view like the picture I have post.

Answer (score 0):

I think yu didn't use the following functions  1.applicationWillResignActive & 2.applicationWillEnterForeground in your Application. so please use this following functions in AppDelegate.m`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
}`

Comment: I already have above function in `AppDelegate.m`. And it has `[self checkViews:application.windows] ;
    [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO] ;` in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. But it is the same...